# Run a function from dropdownlist value in Google app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm new to `Google App Script` and I'm trying to make a dropdownlist using `HtmlService` where it'll run a function depending on the value of the selected item. But nothing is happening after clicking the `OK` button. Here are my codes,

**CODE.GS**

```
function getList()
{
    var myHtml = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(myHtml, 'Select Your Option');
}
```

**HTML**

```
<head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
        document.getElementById("btnGet").onclick = function() {
            var e = document.getElementById("menu");
            var getMenu = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
            if (getMenu == "inbox") {
                google.script.run.my_scrapper(getMenu);
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <select id="menu">
        <option value="inbox">Inbox</option>
        <option value="drafts">Drafts</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <button id="btnGet">OK</button>
</body>
```

How can I run the function & pass the selected item's value as parameter in the function after I click `OK` button in google app script? Need this help badly! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the DOM using getElementById before it has loaded.
Move your script tag after `<body>` tag.
For more about dialogs : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs